# Read file and compare the content in the workseet

Tags: excel, vba

Currently, I am able to compare different sheet in same file. How can I achieve it if I move Sheet3 to another file (Example: File2)? And Sheet1 B2 will return a 'pass' or 'fail' depends on the content match or not.

File1 - Sheet1

[image: Sheet1]

File1 - Sheet2

[image: Sheet2]

File1 - Sheet3

[image: Sheet3]

```
Sub Compare()
    Dim dataLength As Integer
    Dim i As Integer

    dataLength = 100

    Sheet1.Range("B2").Value = "Pass"
    For i = 1 To dataLength
        If Sheet3.Cells(1, i) <> Sheet2.Cells(i, 1) Then
            Sheet1.Range("B2").Value = "Fail"
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Open the external workbook with `Workbooks.Open`
2. Use the external worksheet instead of `Sheet3`

Something like this:

```
Sub Compare()
    Dim dataLength As Long
    dataLength = 100

    Sheet1.Range("B2").Value = "Pass"

    'open the workbook
    Dim ExternalWb As Workbook
    Set ExternalWb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="C:\your folder\your file.xlsx")

    'get the sheet
    Dim ExternalSheet As Worksheet
    Set ExternalSheet = ExternalWb.Worksheets("Sheet3")


    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To dataLength
        If ExternalSheet.Cells(1, i) <> Sheet2.Cells(i, 1) Then
            Sheet1.Range("B2").Value = "Fail"
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```